# How to setup create-react-app with webpack-dev-server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack-dev-server, create-react-app

I'm trying to setup my create-react-app instance with webpack-dev-server.

This is my package.json file

```
{
  "name": "reactgs",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.0.0",
    "react-scripts": "1.0.14"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "webpack-dev-server --entry ./node_modules/react-scripts/bin/react-scripts.js --output-filename ./dist/bundle.js --inline --progress",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.9.1"
  }
}
```

I don't have a webpack.config.js file.

When I run

```
npm run build
```

The output appears as

[image: Screenshot:webpackerror]

The following line runs fine.

```
npm start
```

I also have webpack setup fine on the same machine for a different project.

Does anyone know how to properly configure webpack for create-react-app?

Comment: With `create-react-app`, the `build` command is already preconfigured to run this command: `react-scripts build`, which takes care of everything. I don't quite understand why you need `webpack-dev-server` on the `build` command. Usually, you don't need hosting of your package on a dev server when you build. You usually take the generated assets and put them elsewhere, where they can be served. What exactly is your intent?

Comment: I'm trying to get my create-react-app to perform hot reloading with webpack-dev-server, is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`npm start` does the HMR for you out-of-the box. It will host your application using `webpack-dev-server --hot` itself. You just need to hook the HMR code to tell webpack what to watch and reload as necessary.

This GitHub conversation offers a pretty decent simple solution for hooking HMR (https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/2317) with and without Redux.

Comment: I've tried the changes you suggested but no luck.
I've also read that HMR is enabled for changes to stylesheets by default, but this is not working for me.
I've followed several video guides on how to set this up, but still no luck. I'm thinking it could be because I am using port 1001, since my docker is setup to listen on port 1001.

Comment: Webpack dev server only accepts to serve on the localhost, which may not work with Docker. Is there a particular reason why you are using Docker for local development?

Comment: I still call localhost:1001 to retrieve my project. I ran the create-react-app on my host machine just now and it all worked fine. I'll try spinning up a docker instance on port 3000 later and let you know how it goes.

I mostly just use docker as an alternative to Virtual Box so that I can run linux.